# Scrollable LineChart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am creating an application and use the MPAndroidChart library to draw line chart. I am putting Dates on x-axis and number on y-axis. I am not able to scroll line chart horizontally when there are more data. My snippet is here:

```
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTextSize(8f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setPosition(xAxis.getPosition());
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
 //   xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(1);
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-90.0f);

    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new DefaultYAxisValueFormatter(0));

    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    rightAxis.setValueFormatter(new DefaultYAxisValueFormatter(0));
     LineDataSet barDataSet1 = null;
    if (valueSet1 != null && valueSet1.size() > 0) {
        barDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(valueSet1, "Sended");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        barDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
        barDataSet1.setCircleSize(2.0f);
        barDataSet1.setLineWidth(1.0f);
        barDataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        barDataSet1.setValueTextSize(10.0f);
        barDataSet1.setDrawCubic(true);

    }


    ArrayList dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    if (barDataSet1 != null)
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

    LineData data = new LineData(xDatelist, dataSets);
    if (data != null)
        chart.setData(data);
    chart.setPinchZoom(true);

    chart.setScrollContainer(true);
    chart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
    chart.setDescription("Send/Received files");
    chart.invalidate();
```

Still I am not able to scroll graph when there is more data then date gets compressed on x-axis. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find the answer ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 5):

You can add your chart inside `HorizontalScrollView` to make it scroll. But to do so, you first need to calculate your chart view's desired height and width and programatically set it to chartview.

In the below code, I have temporary set it to some default value to check scrolling behaviour.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart1"
            android:layout_width="1000dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: what about if i have value in yAxis left and yAxis right?

Comment: This is needed if you want the saveToGallery(filename) function to pick up the entire chart(not just what's in the viewport or what's visible.) as image to save.

Answer (score 2):

chart.setData(...); // first set the data.

// now modify viewport
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(7); // allow 7 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis, not more.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use the following methods with your chart:

chart.moveViewToX()

chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum()

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
// we can modify viewport, Scrolling the data from right to left
// allow 30 values to be displayed at once on the x-axis not allow more value 
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(30); 
// set the left edge of the chart to x-index 20
// moveViewToX(...) also calls invalidate()
chart.moveViewToX(20);
```

Check this for more information read [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport)

I hope it'll help you....!

Answer (score 0):

You should just put this code and your problem and issue will be Resolved

use this function:-

**chart.setScrollx();**

In this code you can put any value you want and your graph x-axis line will scroll.

Example : **chart.setScrollX(50);** (*here your value is 50 and your graph x-axis line move or scroll after 50 points*)